# PreparedStatement cannot retrieve based on enumeration using Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, enums, prepared-statement

I'm developing a cinema Database, using PostgreSQL, and implementing it graphically with Java.

Everything is working fine but this: i have a PreparedStatement used in a method  written like this:

```
getFilmByGenrePS = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Film WHERE genre = ?");


public List<Film> getFilmByGenre(String Genre) throws SQLException{
        getFilmByGenrePS.setString(1, Genre);
        ResultSet rs = getFilmByGenrePS.executeQuery();
        List<Film> list = new ArrayList<Film>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            Film f = new Film(rs.getInt("CodF"));
            f.setFilmName(rs.getString("Name"));
            f.setGenreFilm(rs.getString(3));
            f.setLenght(rs.getInt("lenght"));
            f.setCast(rs.getString("castfilm"));
            f.setDirector(rs.getString("director"));
            f.setDate(rs.getDate("date"));
            f.setDateout(rs.getDate("dateout"));
            list.add(f);
        }
        rs.close();
        return list;    
        
        
}
```

Genre is an ENUM TYPE in pgadmin.

Then, in my GUI, i have a Combobox with every Genre listed in it, written like this:

```
JComboBox GenrecomboBox2 = new JComboBox();
            GenrecomboBox2.setBounds(60, 485, 150, 27);
            panelViewFilm.add(GenrecomboBox2);
            
            GenrecomboBox2.addItem("Animation");
            GenrecomboBox2.addItem("Adventure");
            GenrecomboBox2.addItem("Action");
```

Then, I have a button that, when pressed, takes my selected Genre from the Combobox, and passes it to the GetAllFilmByGenre() method as a parameter, so it can substitute it to the '?' in the PreparedStatement.

```
JButton btnViewFilmGenre = new JButton( new AbstractAction("Vai") {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
                    
                    String genreFilm = (String) GenrecomboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tableViewFilm.getModel();
                    model.setRowCount(0);
                    try {
                        
                        List<Film> listfilm = new ArrayList<>();                    
                        listfilm = filmdao.getFilmByGenre(genreFilm);
                        System.out.println(listfilm);
                        for (Film f : listfilm) {
                            Object[] o = new Object[8];
                              o[0] = f.getCodF();
                              o[1] = f.getFilmName();
                              o[2] = f.getDirector();
                              o[3] = f.getGenreFilm();
                              o[4] = f.getCast();
                              o[5] = f.getLenght();
                              o[6] = f.getDate();
                              o[7] = f.getDateEnd();
                              
                            
                              ((DefaultTableModel) tableViewFilm.getModel()).addRow(o);
                        }
                        
                        
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                        System.out.println("");

                    }
                    
                } 
            });
```

Thing is, this does absolutely nothing. Overall, I think the code works. I used exact same versions of these code by retrieving different parameters and it works flawlessly.

Worth noting: the problem is that it doesn't populate my list at all. I tried to print the list after creating it, and nothing shows up. I get no SQLExceptions or anything.

I think the problem is the parameter i pass. Like, the query "SELECT * FROM FILM WHERE Genre = ?" (with ? substituted with, for example, 'Action') gets executed, but simply doesn't find anything that matches, thus giving me nothing. But if I write "SELECT * FROM FILM WHERE Genre = 'Action'", the query works.

I don't know how to resolve this. I used this exact Combobox for inserting values in my Database and it works. I tried for hours. I'm sure I'm slipping on something stupid, maybe the interaction between the String I use as a parameter in substitution of the '?' is wrong on syntax, but i can't get it. Any help?

Comment: Try `genre = cast(? as your_enum_type_name)`